# tr:commandLink action method does not navigate to next page.Instead loads same page again

Tags: jsf, myfaces, jsf-1.2

In my JSF application ,after successful login, i am navigating to my home page of my application where i have a `Logout` link.

Here is the related html for logout link.

```
<div id="top_white">
        <div style="float: right"><tr:form><tr:commandLink id="logout" action="#{Controller.Logout}"><img alt="logout" src="../../images/logout.gif"/></tr:commandLink></tr:form></div>
    </div>
```

And here is my `Controller` which is `sessionscoped`

```
public class Controller {

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class);

    public Controller() {
        req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        session = req.getSession(false);
        String userid = session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
        if(List == null){
            List = new ArrayList<List>();
            List = new DAO().loadListByid(Long.valueOf(userid));
            LOGGER.debug("successfully loaded the list for the user");
        }
    }

    private long Username;
    private String Password=null;
    HttpServletRequest req;
    HttpSession session;


    private List<List> List=null;
    // getter and setters


    public String Logout(){
        session.invalidate();
        LOGGER.debug("In LogOut");
        return "loggedout";
    }
}
```

In the Constructor i check for userid in the session and load specific list to the user.

I also have a `ServletFilter` which checks for some id in each session.If it is not found it redirects to InvalidUser page.My filter is mapped to `/faces/jsp/*` so that for all jsp's in the jsp folder are checked for id in the session.

Here is the `doFilter` method of my filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            LOGGER.debug("In doFilter");
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            LOGGER.debug("request:" + request.getRequestURL().toString());
            try{
                if (session.getAttribute("id") != null) {
                    LOGGER.debug("id found:" + session.getAttribute("id"));
                    chain.doFilter(req, res); // id found, so just continue request.
                } 
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                LOGGER.debug("No id found Exception: ", e);
                response.sendRedirect(properties.getProperty(INVALID_USER_REDIRECTURL, true)); // No id found, so redirect to Invalid user page.

            }

    }
```

I also added a `PhaseListener` to debug JSF life cycle which is taken from [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).

When the page is first loaded i see the following server log with only first and last phases of JSF lifecycle

```
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG SessionFilter - In doFilter
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG SessionFilter - request:http://my homepageurl
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG SessionFilter - id found
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] ERROR org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Configuration objects do not support clean-up. Update aborted
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl - exiting from lifecycle.execute in RESTORE_VIEW(1) because getRenderResponse is true from one of the after listeners
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultLifecycleProviderFactory - Using LifecycleProvider org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG Controller - id found in controller
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG DAOProperties - dao.properties loaded successfully
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG SvrConnection - In JNDI
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG DAO - Successfully connected to database
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG DAO - connection closed
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG Controller - successfully loaded the list for the user
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
```

The above log is as expected because there is no form submission type of stuff.So only first and last phases are listed.

But the real problem comes when i click the `Logout` commandLink which i mentioned in the top of this post.

After i click the `Logout` link, here is the server log.

```
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG SessionFilter - In doFilter
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG SessionFilter - request:http://my homepage url
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG SessionFilter - appid found
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] ERROR org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Configuration objects do not support clean-up. Update aborted
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG Controller - In LogOut
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl - exiting from lifecycle.execute in INVOKE_APPLICATION(5) because getRenderResponse is true from one of the after listeners
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-114] DEBUG LifeCycleListener - END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
["http-bio-8090"-exec-116] DEBUG SessionFilter - In doFilter
["http-bio-8090"-exec-116] DEBUG SessionFilter - request:http://my homepage url
["http-bio-8090"-exec-116] DEBUG SessionFilter - No id found Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

From the above log ,as expected my action method is invoked in the  `INVOKE_APPLICATION` and my controller's `Logout()` method is called and session is invalidated and string `loggedout` is returned.

I have the following navigation rule in the `faces-config.xml`

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/jsp/Services.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>loggedout</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/others/Logout.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
```

But this `navigation-rule` does not execute. Instead in the `RENDER_RESPONSE` Phase, it tries to reload my same home page url.obviously it does not have the `id` in the session which is causing to throw a `NullPointerException`.

I have the jsp's in the respective folders as given above.I am using JSF 1.2 and myFaces 1.2.9.

1)Why navigation-case does not execute?

2)Why it is reloading my home page url again?

Please somebody help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is a logout problem in JSF.Not problem with tr:commandLink.

I read some posts about JSF logout problem here on SO and implemented the same.

It works as expected.

Comment: hey Sreeram!
Could you please be more specific on what your fixed.
I get "ERROR org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Configuration objects do not support clean-up. Update aborted" on an old JSF project after the redeploy to Tomcat. Worst of all, is that it some kind of random. Sometimes I get it sometimes it works fine.